# Problem with FormProcessor extension

Tags: forms

I've been facing an issue as soon as I have installed FormProcessor.
Not only I can't access Form Processors but the extension's installation affected also other parts of CiviCRM.

When I try to access Form Processors or other part of CiviCRM the browser displays the following error:

Recoverable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Civi\FormProcessor\ActionProvider\DefaultData::filterActions() must be an instance of Civi\ActionProvider\Action\AbstractAction, string given in Civi\FormProcessor\ActionProvider\DefaultData->filterActions() (linea 26 di /Users/home/Sites/crm.civihost.it/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/form-processor/Civi/FormProcessor/ActionProvider/DefaultData.php).

CiviCRM version installed is 5.1

Is there any way to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance

Best Regards

Giovanni Dal Mas